# UICollectionVIew inside UIView adds a huge amount of padding to the top of the collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview

I am trying to add collection view to UIView and there is a problem that doesn't make any sense. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccd0c.png). I made the background color of the collection view, to make show the view area more clearly.

If I add the collection view straight to the controller (just like in UICollectionViewController), the top padding doesn't exist.

In this example, I have autolayouted the collection view to resize to the whole view but the problem existed the moment I added collection view to the UIView.

Also, if I add another collection view right after this view, there items start from the top, without any margins.

If there is anything else you need me to provide, I will do it. I think this is a storyboard bug or something because there are no insets, in the view's attributes.

Comment: uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Inset" of the uiviewcontroller, that is under attribute inspector

Comment: do your collection view goes inside the navigation bar???

Comment: No. I just fixed it, realizing that it should.

Comment: How does it look at runtime?